# ¿Cómo es el modelo de negocio de Stack Overflow?

Tags: discusión, stackexchange, meta

Tengo una curiosidad sobre **Stack Overflow**, aunque más que una curiosidad es una duda.

- No he visto publicidad en **Stack Overflow**
- Tampoco alguna sesión en  **Stack Overflow** sobre realizar trabajos mediante Freelancer.

Cuando un usuario no tiene problemas en sí en su código o proyecto quiere realizar algo? Pero sin código.

He observado que suelen mencionar en los **comentarios** que si quieren un proyecto existen lugares donde se puede contratar un freelance.

Entonces me viene la duda:

- Si no hay publicidad.
- Si aquí no existe alguna sección para freenlacer.

¿Cómo obtiene beneficios o qué gana  **Stack Overflow**?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a cómo se financia Stack Overflow como empresa?

Comment: Hola @konamiman sí

Comment: stackoverflow si tiene anuncios https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/engagement/ad-targeting

Comment: creo yo que el titulo deberia ser asi mejor : "¿Cómo es el modelo de negocio de  Stack Exchange" porque se habla de la compañia y no solo de una subred de stack exchange aunque  sea la principal.

Answer (score 13):

De [What is Stack Overflow's business model?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79435/209901), es decir, *¿Cuál es el modelo de negocio de Stack Overflow*, respondida por uno de los fundadores del sitio (Jeff Atwood):

> Tres cosas
>
> 1. Ofertas de trabajo (es decir, el típico modelo de ofertas clasificadas)
>   http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/about-listings
>
> 2. Búsqueda de CVs
>   http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/about-search
>
> 3. La tradicional, pero respetuosa (es decir, sin animaciones ni Flash ni pop-ups) exhibición de anuncios en SO, SF y -algo menos- SU.
>   http://stackexchange.com/about/contact
>
> No es difícil hacer números para estimar cuánto dinero estamos consiguiendo. Recuerda también que la mitad del equipo trabaja remotamente y no vive en Nueva York.

Al punto 3 habría que añadirle lo descrito en [We're enabling display ads on select Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287242/209901)

Comment: Sin olvidar que en el pasado también hemos obtenido [financiación por parte de empresas de capital riesgo](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2015/01/20/stack-exchange-raises-40m), algo importante para una empresa que está empezando.

Comment: En resumen el modelo de negocio de Stack Exchange depende fuertemente de Stack Overflow...

Comment: y esas ofertas de trabajo y la búsqueda de empleo permiten habla español? veo que están solo en ingles.

Comment: @Konamiman de todos modos, una ronda de inversión no creo que compute como ingreso, sino más bien como fuente de financiación. No tengo ni idea de economía, por lo que tal vez estoy diciendo una barbaridad.

Comment: @PabloContreras estoy convencido que sí. Filtra por países y encontrarás muchas ofertas en países hispanohablantes. Eso sí, la mayoría suelen ser de start ups cuyo idioma vehicular es el inglés.

Comment: @fedorqui: Yo sé muy poco de finanzas. Entre lo poco que sé es que hay "inversiones a fondo perdido" que son algo así como los donativos, pero fiscalmente no se les puede llamar donativo por las condiciones que existen para estos últimos. Desconozco si StackOverflow, la empresa ha recibido, y en tal caso sigue recibiendo, este tipo de inversión.

Comment: @Rubén puede que al principio de Stack Overflow se basara en donaciones. He buscado un poco ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow), [2](https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/)) pero no encontré referencias, aunque no me extrañaría porque con algo debieron empezar :) Lo que considero seguro es que ahora no hay tales donativos. Eso sí, [se] sí los hace anualmente: [Stack Overflow Gives Back 2016](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/Stack-Overflow-Gives-Back-2016/), esto es, cada moderador decide a qué destinar 100 dólares de entre una lista.

Answer (score 7):

Agregando a la respuesta de fedorqui, [Nick Craver escribió un excelente artículo actualizado al 2016](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/how-we-make-money-at-stack-overflow-2016-edition/), donde también habla de Stack Overflow Enterprise (donde empresas pueden tener su versión de Stack Overflow dentro de su firewall) y de la filosofía de Stack Overflow cuando se trata de generar plata.